# google prediction api pricing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-prediction

For google prediction api in the documentation pages it'showing different quota limits in different places for 10$ plan.

In the above link its saying that the prediction limits are 10000/day
   https://cloud.google.com/prediction/

whereas in the next link it's saying the limit is 10,000/month
  https://cloud.google.com/prediction/pricing?csw=1

If there is anybody who has used this and could tell me which is the correct one I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's a typo on the first link. 10K free per day seems way too high -
 considering you need to contact Google if you're going to do more than 40K per day (see "Usage Limits).

For now, until a Googler can confirm, I'd go with per month i.e. https://cloud.google.com/prediction/pricing?csw=1